# When to use what features of Durandal?

Tags: architecture, knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

I'm brand new to Durandal and loving it so far, but I'm wondering about some app architecture concerns using it. For example, when is a good time to use `ko: compose` vs widgets vs child views vs views?

**My current thoughts are:**

Use views for full pages

Use child views or `ko: compose` interchangably for child pages

Use widgets for child views used in more than one place

Does that match up with what is the expected use case? I'm aware Durandal is highly customizable, but basing it off the Starter Kit structure and using the default utilities (knockout.js, jquery, sammy, etc.), what are the proper times to use each of the above elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome on board and make sure to go through the docs at http://durandaljs.com/pages/docs/, which provides an good overview.

When looking of Durandal features that allow composition of DOM fragments I typically distinguish between view models that are singletons (unique, there's only one of it) or constructors (could be one or many). By convention view models are paired with an *.html file of the same name.

e.g take a look at the shell.html in the Durandal's [sample shell.html](https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2/blob/gh-pages/App/samples/shell.html) vs. [JumpStarter's shell.html](https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal/blob/master/SPAJumpStart/App/views/shell.html)

In both examples `shell.js` return a singleton as there's only one shell, but the second example extract the navigation html into it's own child view. As you see a child view doesn't have it's own vm it's bound the parent (here `shell.js`) instead. By doing so you create smaller, easier to maintain fragments, which could re-used in other places if needed.

For an example that uses constructor function for the vm check out the [master detail sample](https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2/blob/gh-pages/App/samples/masterDetail/default/project.js).

Widgets are a special form of a vm/view((controller.js/view.html) and might be considered if there's a need to configure those elements slightly different depended on the context they are running in. One example might be form elements running as part of a modal form versus an inline.

With Durandal 1.2 only widgets can receive additional data during composition, but this will change in upcoming 2.0.

Comment: Great explanation, I really appreciated the example shell files to show how different approaches can be taken to accomplish the same task. Other than the Durandal docs, and the John Papa tutorials you have to pay for, are you aware of any other good resources for learning more about this type of architecture, hopefully specifically relating to Durandal?